# Is there anything a copilot can do to stop a pilot from doing anything while flying?

Tags: airline-pilot, regulations

Is there anything a copilot in a commercial aircraft can do to stop a pilot from doing anything while flying?

As I see it, there are two scenarios:

1. The pilot is going to do something malicious, in which case the copilot could physically try to restrain or disable the pilot.
2. It's not malicious, but just something that is a bad idea (say could get the pilot fired or in legal trouble). In my imagination, this could be something like a dangerous like a fly-by.

This question is a different from [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/how-are-conflicts-between-pilot-flying-and-pilot-not-flying-over-aircraft-contro), since the scenario in that question is when the pilots are cooperating but have some misunderstanding on when command is transferred to one from the other, or if one doesn't accept to receive command of the aircraft.

Comment: @Pondlife That question is different

Comment: You mean something other than physically assaulting them? Like are you asking if there is a "disable pilot controls" switch?

Comment: That's why it's only a "possible" duplicate :-) But you may get a better answer if you make it clear why it doesn't help you.

Comment: @Pondlife Updated!

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the answer applies directly: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/does-pilot-monitoring-have-authority-to-go-around-in-exceptional-circumstances/40779#40779

Comment: Just a sidenote, there is no such thing as "pilot" and "copilot". All pilots in the cockpit are equally qualified and either can be the one flying the aircraft.

Comment: @J.Hougaard, really "copilot" is just a more common term for First Officer, and the FO, (while qualified and capable) is generally less qualified than the Captain.

Comment: @MichaelHall Less experience and lower rank within the airline, sure. I'm not sure I would say less qualified

Comment: We are probably splitting hairs here, but a FO is not qualified to be a Captain!  ;)